# unable to change to different user in mysql

Tags: mysql, wamp, wampserver

I am also using windows 7.I installed mysql server 5.1. 
Created a user as 'user@localhost' using mysql console. But unable to login to that user.

I tried to run using command prompt. 
When I created a user with name "user". when i tried  mysql -u user -p
It says Access Denied to 'user@localhost' .. 
Even trying with mysql console is not helping out here. .

Answer (score 0):

A few things to try:

1. Make sure your user has the correct privileges set (global or schema level privileges)
2. try running `FLUSH PRIVILEGES`

To help us troubleshoot, what does this command return? `SHOW GRANTS FOR 'user'@'localhost';`